# Protractor looping of value in sendKeys(index)

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, protractor

How is possible to send value to `sendKeys(value)` in loop?

I tried the different options to figure out it but no luck.

**Numbers.ts**

```
export const Numbers = {
 1: '777',
 2: '777',
 3: '777'
};
```

**Texts.ts**

```
export const Texts = {
  1: '111',
  2: '222',
  3: '333'
};
```

**Code.ts**

```
public async readFromFile(): Promise<void> {
  const numbers: object = Numbers;
  const texts: object = Texts;

  function* generatorNumbersAndTexts(objectNumbers, objectTexts) {
    let i: string;
    let j: string;

    for (i in objectNumbers) {
      for (j in objectTexts) {
        if (objectNumbers.hasOwnProperty(i) &&   objectTexts.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
          yield i;
          yield j;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  for (let indexI of generatorNumbersAndTexts(numbers, texts)) {
    for (let indexJ of generatorNumbersAndTexts(numbers, texts)) {
      texts.hasOwnProperty(indexJ)) {
      await this.clickSendMessage();
      try {
        await this.typeContacts(numbers[indexI]);
      } catch (e) {
        throw new Error(`There is no phone field ${e}`);
      }
      await this.typeMessage(texts[indexJ]);
      await this.sendMessage();
    }
   }
  }
```

**Methods**

These are methods which were used inside readFromFile method.

```
public async typeContacts(numbers: string): Promise<void> {
  await this.contactField.sendKeys(numbers + ';');
}

public async typeMessage(text: string): Promise<void> {
  await this.messageField.type(text);
}

public async type(text: string): Promise<void> {
  await this.clearInput();
  await this.sendKeys(text);
}
```

It seems it might be an issue of Protractor promises.

Comment: What element are you performing `sendkeys()` on? `this.sendKeys(text);` sendKeys must have an element to perform the action on

Comment: @BenMohorc `this.contactField = new Fragment($('div > input[aria-owns="contact-list"]'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to give a fully complete answer without seeing the functions that you reference. However, it is possible to use `sendKeys()` while looping through an object.
Using sendKeys() with a loop:

```
it('Should show a loop',async()=>{
  let elem = $(''); //Input value of element you are sending key to
  let values = {1:'111',2:'222',3:'333'} //test values
  for(let key in values){
    await elem.sendKeys(values[key]);
  }
}
```

This example will send `111222333` to `elem`

Comment: **clickSendMessage method** `public async clickSendMessage(): Promise<void> {
    await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(this.sendMessageButton));
    await browser.actions().mouseMove(this.sendMessageButton).click().perform();
    await this.sendMessageButton.click();
  }`.

Comment: This implementation is returned only first value from object - 111 in my case

Answer (score 2):

It was an issue of Protractor. This is a solution:

```
public async fromJSON(): Promise<void> {
  for (const key in Numbers) {
    if (Numbers.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      for (const text in Texts) {
        if (Texts.hasOwnProperty(text)) {
          await this.screenshot(`./screens/1${key}.png`);
          await this.clickSendMessage();
          await this.screenshot(`./screens/2${key}.png`);
          await this.typeContacts(Numbers[key.toString()]);
          await this.typeMessage(Texts[text.toString()]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```